# How to show content in view with horizontal scrollview?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll

I am making an application in which I am implementing event like as:
In bottom of view a scroll view which is scrolling in horizontal direction. In scroll view I have added some text field and images. It looks like as news channels show breaking news in bottom of screen and update it and when click then show detail screen. I want also do in application so that how can I do that?

What I will do so that I will also get this type of feature in application? 
How use scroll view so that I will show some text in view and when click on that then get detail view?

Answer (score 1):

You can load all the images to an array. And you can design a view having one image view, some text fields and try the below code:

array name: examplearray and view name :exampleview

```
-(void)updateImagesInScrollView
{
     int cnt = [examplearray count];

    for(int j=0; j< cnt; ++j)
    {
        NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"exampleview" 
                                                             owner:self 
                                                           options:nil];

        UIView *myView = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
        exampleview * rview= (exampleview *)myView;
        /* you can get your image from the array and set the image*/ 
        rview.imageview.image = yourimage;
        /*adding the view to your scrollview*/
        [self.ScrollView addSubview:rview];
    }
    /* you need to set  the content size of the scroll view */
    self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(X, self.mHorizontalScrollView.contentSize.height);
}
```

The above code is to display the image and text fields in the horizontal scroll view. 
I suggest you to have a custom button on that view and in that button action you can write code to get detail Screen.